# How can I from bs4 import BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Doesn't work, and gives this error :

```
raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__,attr)    
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should i do ?

Comment: In Python 3.x, the `raise Exception, "foo"` syntax is no longer supported. So you need to install a version of BeautifulSoup that supports Python 3.

Comment: whoud you give me the link of download beautifulsoup ?

Comment: which version of beautifulsoup shoud i download ?

Comment: Better take a look at it 

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be using `pip` to install, so you can simply do

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

That will install the latest BS4, which is 4.3.1 as of 2013-08-15. It supports Python 3.

Comment: where should i write " pip install beautifulsoup" ?

Comment: In your command line shell/terminal. If you don't know how to do that, then I suggest reading pip's documentation first. http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: @Jordan Do you know any online Python IDE which has this installed by itself? tnQ

Comment: No, you should probably just develop locally though

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you are using python3, you should use:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 3):

For Windows...
Go to start menu type cmd right click on cmd icon click run as administrator
then type pip install beautifulsoup4.

It likely will fail to install correctly if you fail to do the above step as even though your windows user is an admin account it does not run all apps as administrator.

Notice the difference if you simply just open cmd without the run as admin.

Remember also when using it like so...

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
```

Will not work as it is not correctly formatted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4
```

Will work correctly as it is CaseSensitive.

Comment: it's `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` not `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4`

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal run below code:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

If you are using **Jupyter notebook** run below code in your python file not in terminal.

```
!pip install beautifulsoup4
```

if it successfully install you get below output:

> Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in
> c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.11.1)

Then run your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```