# Beautifulsoup4 ImportError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, import, importerror

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a31e5d379afe> in <module>
----> 1 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py in <module>
     29 import warnings
     30 
---> 31 from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
     32 from .dammit import UnicodeDammit
     33 from .element import (

ImportError: cannot import name 'builder_registry' from 'bs4.builder' (unknown location)
```

I can not figure out why I am getting this import error. I have try to reinstall beautifulsoup4 several times.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I from bs4 import BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831380/how-can-i-from-bs4-import-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```