# no module named bs4 whenever I try to import

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I am attempting to create a web scraping program but whenever I write: `from bs4 import beautifulsoup`, I always get the error:

> no module named bs4

I installed bs4 by: `pip install beautifulsoup4` and `pip install bs4` but nothing is working.

Comment: What is the output of `pip install bs4`

Comment: when i type pip install bs4 in the cmd prompt it just says requirement already satisfied

Comment: Did you tried these [how-can-i-from-bs4-import-beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831380/how-can-i-from-bs4-import-beautifulsoup/18831754)

Comment: yes i've tried so many ways to install

Comment: And the output of `python -m pip show bs4` is right? Maybe `python -m pip install -U bs4` could help.

Comment: Perhaps it's a syntax error judging by how you spelt `beautifulsoup`, have you tried importing it while the first letters of the two words capitalised, i.e. ```from bs4 import BeautifulSoup```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that your program's project uses virtual environment (venv) without bs4. If it is so - install bs4 directly into your venv on your own:

1. Open cmd
2. Type `cd path\to\your\project`
3. Find your virtual environment folder ("venv"/"virtualenv"/etc.)
4. Find "activate" in your venv (for "venv" type in cmd `venv\Scripts\activate`)
5. Try to install bs4 one more time.

Note: some IDEs (like PyCharm) have easier ways for it (like 'settings' button or built-in console with activated venv in it).

In your case (for PyCharm):

Variant 1

At the bottom there will be a panel with different consoles, etc:
TODO, Problems, Terminal, Python Packages, Python Console,... Open [Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdNPA.png). it has to have a [row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F17K.png) like:

`(venv) C:\path\to\your\PyCharmProjects\ProjectName>`

Use this console to check if bs4 is installed for your project (you can just try to install one more time with `pip install bs4`)

---

Variant 2

Press Ctrl+Alt+S -> Project -> Python Interpreter

Check if bs4 is installed for your projects in the [appeared packages list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwBjT.png). If not: press "+"(button above the list), type in 'beautifulsoup' or 'bs4', choose an appropriate package and click "Install Package"

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely new to python so I don't really understand. I'm using pycharm, is there a simpler way to install it through pycharm? Thanks so much and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Kai , I updated my answer (added 2 solutions that can be helpful for you). Please, check it one more time

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen('https://my_site/').read()
read_data = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out if your machine even installed it with:

```
import bs4 

bs4.__version__
```

Then run:

```
import bs4 as bs
```

If it's still not working look at pip itself and re-install it:

```
pip --version

sudo pip uninstall pip

sudo easy_install pip
```