Python Web Scraping: code output: soup not defined
My Yahoo stocks Webscraping program giving me errors.
Please find code below
def getdata(symbol):
    headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XPEV{symbol}'
    r = requests.get(url,headers=header)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    stock ={
        symbol== symbol,
        price== soup.find('fin-streamer',{'class':("Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").text}),
        change== soup.find('fin-streamer',{'class':("Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px").text}),
    
   }
   print(soup.title.text)


I need the help of those more knowledgeable than myself to assist me in debugging the code.
I HAVE TRIED ALMOST EVERTHING TO THE BEST OF MY ABILITY. PLEASE I NEED A MENTOR TO GUIDE ME ON THIS JOURNEY.

you likely did not import Beautiful soup correctly, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831380/how-can-i-from-bs4-import-beautifulsoup

There are many syntax error in your code, so focus first to fix them. Here is the example how you could get the price/change of the stock from that site:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getdata(symbol):
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
    url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}"
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    stock = {
        "symbol": symbol,
        "price": soup.find(
            "fin-streamer", {"class": "Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"}
        ).text,
        "change": soup.find(
            "fin-streamer", {"class": "Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)"}
        ).text,
    }
    return stock


symbol = "XPEV"
print(getdata(symbol))

Prints:
{'symbol': 'XPEV', 'price': '7.47', 'change': '-0.81'}


Much Respect Andrej. I find your code so elegant. You didn't change my method much you just refined it. That was beautiful
